# CentOS: how to fix GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.LimitsExceeded (Maximum active connections)?

Tags: centos, centos7, dbus

On a CentOS 7 server I'm getting this error while trying to reboot:

> # reboot
>   Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.LimitsExceeded: The maximum number of active connections for UID 0 has been reached (g-dbus-error-quark, 8)
>   Failed to start reboot.target: Connection timed out

Or to restart Apache httpd:

> # systemctl restart httpd.service
>   Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.LimitsExceeded: The maximum number of active connections for UID 0 has been reached (g-dbus-error-quark, 8)
>   Failed to restart httpd.service: Connection timed out

What do the mentioned active connections refer to?
How do I stop some of the active connections that are not needed anymore in order to free some slots?